# Mobile Broadband, Windows, Router routing

Tags: windows, router, routing, broadband

I have a DGN2200v4 router (192.168.0.1), connecting 3 PCs.
DHCP is enabled by default.
One pc have a wifi broadband modem connected to internet (10.220.3.6) let say, router DHCP ip  (192.168.0.2).

I want to share broadband modem internet (10.220.3.6), via router so that other 2 pc's can use internet via third one's wifi broadband modem.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use an internet connection that is provided by WiFi, but you'd like all the computers in your home to use it. This is a non-standard setup and you'll have a lot of difficulty accomplishing this, and 1 computer will have remain on for the other 2 to have access.

What you want to do is turn on internet connection sharing on the computer that has the WiFi internet connection - and then you have to turn DHCP OFF on the router so that this computer distributes IP addresses.

I don't recommend this setup, it's not very elegant and prone to errors. You could potentially get a router that supports acting as a wireless bridge or repeater, which is a better, but still imperfect solution. Tomato and DD-WRT can do this, as well some ordinary wireless repeaters, but your mileage may vary in terms of stability.

Comment: So you are saying that, I should turn of DHCP and assign ips to all three computers separately and gateway.
I think there won't be any connectivity between three of them then, because if I turn off DHCP and make 192.168.0.2 PC 1 192.168.0.3 PC 2 192.168.0.4 PC 3 making PC 1 gateway 192.168.0.1 (route ip) and PC 2 and PC 3 gateway 192.168.0.2(PC 1 IP internet connected). Will this work ? Will I be able to ping to internet via PC 2 and PC 3.Keeping internet on PC 1.(Through other modem/network device) ???

Comment: if you turn on internet connection sharing in windows, Windows will act as a DHCP server, so the router DHCP has to be off. You don't need assign manual IPs on the other computers.

While doing your testing it's easier to try with 2 computers at once and remove the router from the setup.

Comment: But how will I connect two PC then with one PC ?, I would have to buy long wire and three more network cards to do so. That's why I brought router for. Is there any way I can use router and connect all three PCs and share one's internet connectivity and let others use that shared connection ?

Comment: you need at least 1 wire to make this work - from the router to the computer that has the wifi network.

It's a very challenging setup, you'd best get a router that can act as a repeater, that's the most sane solution.

Comment: I have connected all the wires from all 3 PCs to router. I just have to disable router DHCP and enable windows DHCP on all three PCs, while sharing internet connection from PC 1. Will it work ? If I disable router DHCP then how PC 1 will negotiate with PC 2 and PC 3, automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. 
I shared wifi modem network with Ethernet of pc 1 which was connected to router.
The ip of PC 1 Ethernet card changed automatically to 192.168.197.1 after enabling network sharing. I changed router ip to 192.168.197.2 and disabled DHCP on the router. Then I configured PC 2 and PC 3 as 192.168.197.3 and 192.168.197.4 with gateway 192.168.197.1.

If I want traffic to go through my router then simple I can change PC 2 and PC 3 network gateway as 192.168.197.2 and add a static route rule as internet_ips(0.0.0.0) 255.255.255.255(0.0.0.0) 192.168.197.1.

Thanks everyone and especially #cloneman...